# Using Google Authentication for my Java Web App

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am trying to develop an a business application. I intend to host it on Google App Engine and use Google DataStore as a backend database. How can my users register with the application using their Google, Yahoo and Facebook accounts apart from the naive conventional sign up method? When ever the user registers using the aforementioned third party services how does my DataStore gets updated with the users details? help me to plan the logic

Answer (score 1):

I hope this help.

You can use [Federated Login(OpenId)](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/openid) for that.
Each provider has its own particular data structure(name, userName, country, language, etc).

Regards.

Comment: Keep in mind that Facebook uses Facebook Connect and is not a traditional Open ID provider.